Swift - Verifying a fileID makro
I am developing an SDK in Swift. I want to make a method that receives a String representing a fileID and checks if the provided String is indeed a real fileID of the application.
I have tried to extract the file path from that fileID so I could validate it that way but I don't see how. I have tried to iterate over all Bundles and look for the file name but It does not work.
There is no official way to get the Bundle or path from a fileID? Or another other way to certificate that the String correspond to a real fileID?

There is no file path you can get from #fileID. It is deliberately designed this way to provide better privacy. How about using #filePath instead?
